# Send variable from php to python

Tags: php, python, web, remote-server

Here is my problem, I need to send a variable to a python script from php which isn't really that hard but I just found out that they are not on the same server. The php file is on server A and can be accessed at server-a.com and the python is on a different server that can be accessed at server-b.com.

This is my current code for the php and python which works when they are on the same server:

PHP:

```
// Call to the python script test.py with the JSON data
$result = shell_exec('python test.py ' . escapeshellarg(json_encode($data)));

// get data back from python, decode it and display it
$resultData = json_decode($result, true);
//var_dump($resultData);
echo $result;
?>
```

Python:

```
    import sys, json

# Load the data that PHP testv2.php sent us
try:
    data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
except:
    print "ERROR"
    sys.exit(1)

# Generate some data to send to PHP
result = {'status': 'Yes!'}

# Send it to PHP
print json.dumps(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on different servers you probably want to communicate via HTTP.

If your code is really THAT simple like shown in your example and will never become more complex, consider invoking Python via [CGI](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html).

For anything else (or if you simply prefer doing it properly) consider using WSGI and a framework such as Flask which allows you to define multiple endpoints using an url routing system.